# How to "dispose" an EntityManager

Tags: breeze

We've taken the approach of creating a new EntityManager each time we load an view for editing a record (to support a unit-of-work pattern).

Is there anything special we need to do to allow the EntityManager to be garbage collected?  I believe we are releasing all references to the manager but Chrome's "Take Heap Snapshot" tool doesn't show the EntityManager (or any entities) being deleted when we leave our view.

I see that each entity's `entityAspect.entityManager` holds a reference to the manager.  Does that prevent everything from getting garbage collected?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that calling `entityManager.clear()` is required to detach all entities from the manager which then allows everything to get garbage collected.

Comment: That is correct, each entity holds a reference to its entityManager and the entityManager keeps track of all of its entities. So to clear memory you need to detach all of the entities from the entityManager and throw away any refs to the entities.  The EntityManager.clear does the first of these, but you still need to "lose" any refs to any of the entities.

Comment: If I loose all references to the entityManager and it's entities, shouldn't this be sufficient for everything to be garbage collected, without calling entityManager.clear()?

Comment: It is very convenient that each entity holds a reference to it's manager but that does create a circular reference.  The entities keep the manager alive, and the manager keeps the entities alive.  The only was to tear the whole thing down is to call `entityManager.clear()`

Comment: There are more circular references involved here. For example bidirectional associations or EntityAspect's back reference to Entity.

Comment: I think entityManager.clear() allows you to detach the entities, when you want to keep the manager.

Comment: @pawel - yes, if nothing holds a reference to *any* entity in cache or to the manager, they will all be GCd together. However. if something holds a reference to just one entity, then that entity keeps its EntityManager alive and the manager keeps the other entities alive. So everything goes or none of it goes. That's why clearing the manager is a pretty good safety step. If only JavaScript supported weak references ... we can dream.

Comment: @Ward Your dreams are becoming true :P I can't wait for this to be more widely implemented [weakRef](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef)